# FreeType not linking with CMake after explicit path to library given.

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, freetype

I have an issue with linking FreeType with my project. I have my libs in a separate folder, {PROJECT}/lib, where libfreetype.a is located. My compiler is MinGW-64 4.8.3 x86_64-posix-seh-rev2, and I built libfreetype.a from source using this compiler. My cmake file looks like the following:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Build/Debug")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lmingw32")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include) 
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

set(FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/)
set(FREETYPE_LIBRARY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libfreetype.a)
find_package(Freetype REQUIRED)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp ...)

add_executable(Wahoo ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Test freetype)
```

Running this will cause the linker to fail with undefined references to '__imp_FT_Init_FreeType'. Removing the the libfreeType.a causes CMAKE say that it cannot find -lfreeType (as expected), but including libfreetype.a will cause the linker errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have to change my answer, because I tried it on my own and it was bullshit.

I think, you have to change only your last line into

```
target_link_libraries(Test ${FREETYPE_LIBRARY})
```